# Auto complete box with multiple values in SharePoint Web Part using J query and SharePoint list web service

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, jquery, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2010 Questions.

I am trying to create an auto suggesting text-box with multiple values in a SharePoint web part. 
i am using j query and SharePoint list web services to do it. 
I am just learning to do these stuffs but not getting a result. 
Any help much appreciated.

Following is the code. 
i am creating an alert to see if i get any data but it alerts a blank dialog

this is my latest code

```
var restServiceAddress = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/";
var listName = "Topics";
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}  

  $(document).ready(function () {


    $('#<%=input_title.ClientID%>').autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                url: "" + restServiceAddress + listName,
                data: "{'Title':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return item.Title;

                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function () {
            return false;

        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        },
        minlength: 1

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are mixing up two different types of Web services: the legacy ones (lists.asmx) and the REST services that come with SharePoint 2013.

Assuming that you are working with SharePoint 2013, the url for your ajax call should look like this:

```
http://<site url>/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items?$filter=startswith...
```

Comment: i am working with SharePoint 2010. This is the first time i am trying to do this. Is the URL correct for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: For SP 2010, see @PirateEric's answer. For such questions, it's important to tell which version of SharePoint you are working with.

Comment: Updated the code with my latest work, the latest codes gives me a null error. I am not able to send the starts with character in the URl how do i do that...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use REST, your URL is wrong and is why it isn't working. It needs to be `http://mysite.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/mylist`

If you are trying to use the SOAP based web services, then that is not right either. I'd suggest using a library like [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to help interact with the SOAP web services.

Comment: i added the SPServices but everytime i define a spservices object it says object not defined. I am not sure why it is not recognized SPServices as object. I tried this                 var thisSite = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite(); It says cannot find SPServices.

Comment: Then this means you don't have your file references right. jQuery needs to load first, then SPServices, then your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery and SP services
Explained step by step here https://jsharepoint.wordpress.com/2017/05/24/auto-complete-control-using-sp-services/

Comment: please don't post link as answer . If the link is broken then the answer has no use .